# Why does Alfresco Moodle integration bounce my login?

Tags: soap, alfresco, moodle

I have Moodle running on 2 different servers hosted by 2 different platforms (AWS and Rackspace).

I have configured the AWS Moodle installation to read from Alfresco through the repository plugin and it works perfectly with the URL https://myinstall/alfresco/soapapi

On the Rackspace Moodle installation, I set it up the same way and I can see the login box but it won't accept my credentials for Alfresco. I press login and it clears out the username and password boxes.

I installed SOAP properly and enabled Web Services on both. Is this a networking issue?

Comment: have you checked connectivity of your alfresco instance from Rackspace?

Comment: Yes and it is working.

Comment: In that case it should work. Are you getting any error in logs of alfresco?Have you tried with CMIS APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Note:](https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Alfresco_repository) The Alfresco plugin does not work with Alfresco 5.0.c or later. It is intended eventually to remove this repository from standard Moodle and include it in the Plugins directory.